# Opening a New Window in a New Session with Javascript in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, session, vbscript, internet-explorer-8

We are migrating at work to Internet Explorer 8 and we are confronted to the new "feature" the so called "Session Merging", all new windows from IE8 share the same Session Cookie. 
That's creating some problems because we have a Web based system that must permit work in parallel in several windows, but each must have it's own Session (mostly Session variables used in legacy code).

Now, I remember when I was developing a feature for this system that involved opening a new window from an existing one using javascript to have seen something in the MSDN documentation about a new parameter that you can pass in IE8 to get a new session. I have been searching the MSDN documentation for 2 days now and I can't find that I have seen more or less a year ago.

Does anybody knows how I can't say to IE8 it should use a new session for the window in Jscript or VBscript?

Regards

Vlax

Answer (score 0):

This might or might not help, I am unable to test at the moment, but if you add the -nomerge switch the to the short cut you use when you first open the web application, does this prevent subsequent new windows to spawn without sharing the session?

Comment: Hi Tristan thanks for your answer, and yes it does but it's not was I'm trying to achieve. For the matter you can use a registry entry as well. 
But what I'm trying to achieve is to open a new "pop up" window from a web application that gets a new session id.
Right now I'm using a call to an ActiveX Wscript.Shell to be able to call the iexplorer exe and then I insert the nomerge modifier there.
But that solution is unelegant and pops a message everytime asking for permission to run ActiveX controls...
I'm sure I read somewhere there is a new parameter to tell IE8 to start a new session...

Comment: Just I can't remember, find it anymore ... :-(